# Задача о рюкзаке для нахождения лучшего рецепта зелья

Tags: алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

Возникла проблема при решении самопридуманной задачи.

Недавно я начал играть в игру Potionomic. В ней необходимо варить зелья в котле, используя ингредиенты.

Каждое зелье варится по определённой пропорции магического элемента `[A, B, C, D, E]`. Это всегда простые пропорции `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]` или `[0, 0, 3, 3, 4]`.

Каждый ингредиент ( их порядка 200 ) содержит в себе магический элемент `[A, B, C, D, E]` определённого размера. Это может быть один или несколько сразу, например `[8, 0, 0, 0, 0]` или `[0, 24, 8, 0, 12]`. Каждые два ингредиента в котле - это 1 зелье на выходе. Закинем 6 ингредиентов - получим 3 зелья в результате.

Котлы же различаются количеством ингредиентов, которые можно в них положить (4, 6, 8, 10, 12 ( выше не видел )), а так же максимумом суммы магических элементов ( то есть нельзя положить в чан с максимумом в 100 магии два ингредиента с магией по 70 ).

Это три базовых концепции, вокруг которых строится варка.

Пример:

Возьмём зелье с пропорцией `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]`.Берём ингредиент `[8, 0, 0, 0, 0]` и ингредиент `[0, 8, 0, 0, 0]`. Результат - `[8, 8, 0, 0, 0]` - чистая пропорция 50/50. Результат 1 зелье.
Докинем еще по одному таких же и получим `[16, 16, 0, 0, 0]` - всё тоже отлично, но уже два зелья.

---

И я решил написать программу, которая будет принимать мои ингредиенты, рецепт нужного зелья и размеры моего котла.

По первой всё было прекрасно. Это был тупой перебор всех комбинаций и проверкой каждой на соответствие пропорций.
Но когда дело дошло до... даже не середины, а 2/5 всей игры я получил котёл на 8 ингредиентов и максимумом 240 магии.
+ к тому времени количество ингредиентов увеличилось. То есть применяя фильтры было где-то по 20 на одно зелье.

Начались гугления, сросы у знакомых и звонки сыну маминой подруги. Результат меня привёл к "Задача о рюкзаке".
Ура, подумал я, но после пары попыток реализаций я думаю, что это тот же тупой перебор. Просто в других декорациях.

Мой текущий код:

```rb
def select_items(ingredients, magimin, potion)
  keys = magimin.select { potion.receipt_keys.include? _1 }.group_by { _2 }.min_by { _1 }&.last&.map { _1[0] }
  return ingredients if keys.nil?

  ingredients.select do |ingredient|
    keys.any? do |k|
      ingredient.send(k) > 0
    end
  end
end

def knapsack(ingredients, max_ingredients, max_magimin, current_magimin = nil, lookup = nil, brew: nil, potion:, cc:)
  lookup ||= {}
  brew ||= []
  current_magimin ||= {}

  return [] if max_ingredients.zero?

  return lookup[brew.map(&:id).sort] if lookup.include?(brew.map(&:id).sort)

  items = select_items(ingredients, current_magimin, potion)

  max_value = []
  items.each do |ingredient|
    if ingredient.total_magimin <= max_magimin
      new_brew = brew + [ingredient]
      new_current_magimin = [current_magimin, ingredient.hash_magimin].reduce({}) do |s, l|
        s.merge(l) { |_, a, b| a + b }
      end
      new_comb = [ingredient] + knapsack(ingredients, max_ingredients - 1, max_magimin - ingredient.total_magimin, new_current_magimin, lookup, brew: new_brew, potion: potion, cc: cc)

      cc[:count] += 1 if max_ingredients == 1
      if new_comb.sum(&:total_magimin) > max_value.sum(&:total_magimin) && (max_ingredients != 1 || Brew.valid?(new_brew, potion.receipt))
        max_value = new_comb
      end
    end
  end
  lookup[brew.map(&:id).sort] = max_value

  max_value
end
```

Он сейчас работает, но и как первая версия, но 8 элементах начинает долго отвечать. И я имею в виду > 10 минут. Я бы хотел знать это вообще долго или нормально для набора данных из 20 ингредиентов на 8 мест? Или мой алгоритм реально не очень?

Подскажите - это нормальный код? Или это реально просто тупой перебор, только в профиль? Нормально ли ждать ответа по 15 минут или это проблемы оптимизации алгоритма?

Comment: Задача рюкзака - по-прежнему имеет точное решение только методом полного перебора. И да, полный перебор такого количества вариантов - это долго. Тут дело не в вашей реализации, а в самом методе полного перебора. Ведь количество перестановок возрастает экспоненциально. Для 3 элементов - 6 перестановок, для 8 - 40 тыс, для 10 элементов - 3,5 млн. Есть даже отдельный раздел - комбинаторика. Есть например генетические алгоритмы, но они не дают 100%-гарантии нахождения лучшего решения. А так просто применяют различные эмпирические стратегии для ограничения количества вариантов.

Comment: @DmitryK, хорошо. То есть мне смотреть в сторону генетических алгоритмов, если я готов принять даже не точные результаты? И, если знаете, можете подсказать какие-нибудь примеры реализации?